# Class with @RequestMapping is never used

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to write REST server, using [this](https://youtu.be/ZA4ziAFVFDU?list=PLIU76b8Cjem4axtgg9DsrJ1y6tyrW9F2K&t=497) video example (careful, russian speech). 
In the example, when lecturer writes @RequestMapping above controller class, class becomes in use. But in my case, controller class "is never used", and when I started tomcat server with my controller and going on page http://localhost:8000/app/remind/get , I get this error: **No mapping for GET /app/remind/get**

This is my controller code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reminder")
public class ReminderController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String getReminder(){
        return "my reminder";
    }
}
```

And this is my WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.fillooow.remindme.server")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

So, can you explain, why my class "is never used" and what am I missing?

**EDIT**
My problem was wrong context in configuration file ("/" instead of "/app")

Comment: You defined your controller with `reminder` path but accessing it with `remind` path. Try `app/reminder/get`.

Comment: The path you're using is `/remind/get`. Look at your annotation. Is that the path it specifies?

Comment: same thing, but now: No mapping for GET /app/reminder/get

Comment: Is your application context *really* `/app`?  I'm *pretty* sure that the default context is `/` which would make your path just `/remind/get`, not `/app/remind/get`.  If you've explicitly set `/app` somewhere, show your configuration (likely an `application.properties` file).

Comment: Yeah, it was really "/", not "/app". Thanks

Comment: Okay, cool.  I'm gonna chalk this one up to being a typo and vote to close it as such.

Comment: @voodoobar - Please do consider using `@PostMapping`, `@GetMapping`, etc.  "Equivalent" ... but arguably "cleaner" ;)

Comment: Sometime I'm also facing same issue. If u got solution please post it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the endpoint like as below

```
 http://localhost:8000/reminder/get
```

Comment: nope, still same:
No mapping for GET /app/reminder/get

Comment: I'm not sure who marked you down. Here's an upvote :)

Answer (score -1):

Suggestion: try @GetMapping; be sure you're using the correct URL:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reminder")
public class ReminderController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/get")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getReminder(){
        return "my reminder";
    }
}
```

... and ...

```
http://localhost:8000/app/reminder/get
```

ALSO: I'm not sure about your context root ("app") or your port ("8000" vs. "8080").

POSSIBLE ALTERNATIVE:

```
http://localhost:8080/reminder/get
```

ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION: Enable debugging

```
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Comment: `@GetMapping` would be the exact same thing the OP is doing, since that convenience annotation is effectively a `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)`.

Comment: ...so why'd you suggest it if you knew it would accomplish nothing...?  Man, I'm not happy about being shouted at...